# Some property of half-planes in Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider the Cartesian product of the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard Euclidean metrics. *An open half-plane* is any set of pairs of real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+b> y$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. If $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ are half-spaces then the following is true:
\begin{equation}\tag{$\ast$}
(\alpha\subseteq\gamma)\wedge(\beta\subseteq\gamma)\longrightarrow(\alpha\subseteq\beta)\vee(\beta\subseteq\alpha)
\end{equation}
Could someone please exhibit a (relatively) simple non-euclidean model in which this property fails? It fails, for example, in Poincaré half-plane model but my question is whether there is a simpler construction with $(\ast)$ false.

Comment: $\wedge$ and $\vee$ are the standard logical operators of conjunction and disjunction. I added brackets to clarify the meaning.

Comment: I am not sure what is simpler than hyperbolic plane in this regard. Is there a reason you do not like it?

Comment: There is nothing I do not like about hyperbolic plane. I was just wondering if there is some more elementary structure in which $(\ast)$ fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It partly depends on what you mean by "noneuclidean model". Here is one example:

Take a bounded open convex region D in the plane, say a triangle or a disk (the latter will be very familiar). Now, declare "lines" in D to be intersections of D with Euclidean lines. Define half-spaces in D similarly. Does it count as "geometry"?  Note that in the case of an ellipse, you will exactly get the hyperbolic geometry. 
If you accept my example as a geometry, then it will violate the half-space property as you wanted. Do you also want a metric in your geometry? How about just using the Euclidean metric? Do not like this (it's incomplete)? Then use Hilbert metric defined via cross ratios.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need.